# MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter: Lost connection: Connection lost; retrying

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-mqtt

Please can someone why the Patho MQTT v3 Message Driven Adapter is continuously loosing connection when trying to subscribe to an HiveMQ 4.9 topic

Versions :

- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-mqtt:5.5.2
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.5.3
- org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.5

Here is the config:

```
@Bean
public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory() {
    DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
    MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
    options.setServerURIs(new String[] { "tcp://localhost:1883" });
    factory.setConnectionOptions(options);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter inboundAdapter(MqttPahoClientFactory clientFactory) {
    return new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("MyApp", clientFactory, "MyTopic");
}
```

Each time the ChannelAdapter issue this error :

```
2022-10-26 15:22:24.580  INFO 28190 --- [nio-8091-exec-1] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer@9490cb2
2022-10-26 15:22:24.917 ERROR 28190 --- [TT Rec: MyoApp] .m.i.MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : Lost connection: Connection lost; retrying...
2022-10-26 15:22:35.241 ERROR 28190 --- [TT Rec: MyoApp] o.s.i.m.outbound.MqttPahoMessageHandler  : Lost connection; will attempt reconnect on next request
```

Please does somebody know the real impact of this situation and what I can do to stop these erros ?

Thanks

Comment: How does it work with the latest Spring Integration `5.5.15`: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#learn ?

Comment: @ArtemBilan thx for your reply. I have the same issue with `5..5.15`

Comment: OK. Are you sure that there is a connection to your HiveMQ then?

Comment: I found the solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48232793/14777359
Thx @Artem Bilan

Comment: Oh! That's nice. It probably would help more if there is more info in the error message for the cause of that lost exception